# Applying friction separately to forward and side directions

Tags: physics, 3d

I'm making a movement-based, first-person 3D game where the player should be able to gain a lot of horizontal speed over time with WASD, but also will stop due to friction very quickly the moment they release their movement key. The player's current horizontal movement is a velocity stored in a 2-dimensional vector.

Due to the requirement of needing to stop fast, I have a high amount of friction applied (the velocity is multiplied by `0.7`.) However, in order to allow gaining high amounts of horizontal speed, the friction is much, much lower when the player is moving, `0.99`.

I intend to separate the friction for forward/back from the friction for left/right, as this allows the player finer control over the current directions they're moving in.

Unfortunately, my code is broken, resulting in it working exactly as I intend only when you're facing in a cardinal direction — every other time, you have far too much friction. At this point, I realise that I'm not really sure what I'm doing, and my guesses aren't panning out. **How do I correctly apply friction separately to the forwards/backwards and side directions?**

I don't really want to include it in the question, but in case it's necessary, here's my current code — JavaScript, with a custom Vec2 class.
`powXY` is `v1.x **= v2.x; v1.y **= v2.y`. Everything else should be self-explanatory.

````
const direction = this.CAMERA.rotation.y;
const forwardBackVector = Vec2.fromDirection(direction).abs();
const leftRightVector = Vec2.fromDirection(direction + Math.PI / 2).abs();

let forwardBackInput = 0;
let leftRightInput = 0;

if (this.KEYBOARD.isDown("KeyE"))
    forwardBackInput++;
if (this.KEYBOARD.isDown("KeyD"))
    forwardBackInput--;

if (this.KEYBOARD.isDown("KeyS"))
    leftRightInput++;
if (this.KEYBOARD.isDown("KeyF"))
    leftRightInput--;

let forwardBackFriction = new Vec2(this.FRICTION).powXY(...forwardBackVector.xy);
let leftRightFriction = new Vec2(this.FRICTION).powXY(...leftRightVector.xy);

const acceleration = Vec2.ZERO;
if (forwardBackInput) {
    const normalisedVector = Vec2.fromDirection(direction + (forwardBackInput === 1 ? 0 : Math.PI));
    const dot = this.horizontalVelocity.dot(normalisedVector) * this.horizontalVelocity.length();
    acceleration.add(normalisedVector
        .multiply(dot < this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL_CAP ? this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL_FAST : this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL)
        .multiply(delta)
        .multiply(leftRightInput ? 0.5 : 1));

    forwardBackFriction = new Vec2(this.FRICTION_MOVE).powXY(...forwardBackVector.xy);
}

if (leftRightInput) {
    const normalisedVector = Vec2.fromDirection(direction + Math.PI / 2 * leftRightInput);
    const dot = this.horizontalVelocity.dot(normalisedVector) * this.horizontalVelocity.length();
    acceleration.add(normalisedVector.copy()
        .multiply(dot < this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL_CAP ? this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL_FAST : this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL)
        .multiply(delta)
        .multiply(forwardBackInput ? 0.5 : 1));

    leftRightFriction = new Vec2(this.FRICTION_MOVE).powXY(...leftRightVector.xy);
}

this.horizontalVelocity.add(acceleration);

this.CAMERA.position.x -= this.horizontalVelocity.y * delta;
this.CAMERA.position.z -= this.horizontalVelocity.x * delta;

for (const friction of [forwardBackFriction, leftRightFriction]) {
    this.horizontalVelocity.x *= friction.x ** delta;
    this.horizontalVelocity.y *= friction.y ** delta;
}
```
````

Comment: Another way to attack this, rather than using selective friction, is using selective traction — with a higher stopping traction. [I show an example of that kind of approach here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/191346/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory unfortunately I don’t think that’s gonna work for my case, because I’ll need to change friction in the air as well, switching to low friction when movement isn’t even a thing. Selective traction would be a good secondary tool, at least. For now I’m gonna need to just figure out how to do friction though

Comment: I'd use a different physics model in mid air. The physics of an airborne biped are very different than those of a biped with their feet on the ground. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple to do with a dot product to project the velocity onto a unit vector, to get the component of the velocity pointing in that direction:

```
function getComponentInDirection(vector, unitDirection) {
    // I'm not sure how your vector library works, so I'll be conservative 
    // and assume we need an explicit copy when we want to avoid modifying the argument.
    const component = unitDirection.copy();

    // Scale this vector to the length of the projection of the input onto this direction.
    // (Incidentally, this dot product is your speed along the given direction)
    component.multiply(unitDirection.dot(vector)); 
    return component;
}
```

With that in hand, you can split your velocity into two parts, scale each one separately, then add them back together again.

```
function applyDirectionalFriction(velocity, forwardDirection, 
                                  forwardFriction, sidewaysFriction, delta)
{
    // Get the component facing forward/backward (assuming forwardDirection has length 1)
    const forwardVelocity = getComponentInDirection(velocity, forwardDirection);

    // Whatever remains after subtracting the forward velocity must be sideways.
    const sidewaysVelocity = (velocity.clone()).subtract(forwardVelocity);

    // Apply the respective friction values to each.
    forwardVelocity.multiply(forwardFriction ** delta);
    sidewaysVelocity.multiply(sidewaysFriction ** delta);

    // Re-combine into a finished velocity.
    return fowardVelocity.add(sidewaysVelocity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I knew that I could get it to work with velocity on the x or y axes, but I had no idea how to fix it when your direction wasn't on those axes. So I had the idea to just rotate the velocity to be on the x/y axes, apply the friction, then rotate back. It feels a little overcomplicated calculation-wise, but it works, and it's comprehensible, so it seems like the way to go.

Here's my updated code:

```
const direction = this.CAMERA.rotation.y;

let forwardBackInput = 0;
let leftRightInput = 0;

if (this.KEYBOARD.isDown("KeyE"))
    forwardBackInput++;
if (this.KEYBOARD.isDown("KeyD"))
    forwardBackInput--;

if (this.KEYBOARD.isDown("KeyS"))
    leftRightInput++;
if (this.KEYBOARD.isDown("KeyF"))
    leftRightInput--;

let forwardBackFriction = this.FRICTION;
let leftRightFriction = this.FRICTION;

const acceleration = Vec2.ZERO;
if (forwardBackInput) {
    const normalisedVector = Vec2.fromDirection(direction + (forwardBackInput === 1 ? 0 : Math.PI));
    const dot = this.horizontalVelocity.dot(normalisedVector) * this.horizontalVelocity.length();
    acceleration.add(normalisedVector
        .multiply(dot < this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL_CAP ? this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL_FAST : this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL)
        .multiply(delta)
        .multiply(leftRightInput ? 0.5 : 1));

    forwardBackFriction = this.FRICTION_MOVE;
}

if (leftRightInput) {
    const normalisedVector = Vec2.fromDirection(direction + Math.PI / 2 * leftRightInput);
    const dot = this.horizontalVelocity.dot(normalisedVector) * this.horizontalVelocity.length();
    acceleration.add(normalisedVector.copy()
        .multiply(dot < this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL_CAP ? this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL_FAST : this.SPEED_HORIZONTAL)
        .multiply(delta)
        .multiply(forwardBackInput ? 0.5 : 1));

    leftRightFriction = this.FRICTION_MOVE;
}

this.horizontalVelocity.add(acceleration);

this.CAMERA.position.x -= this.horizontalVelocity.y * delta;
this.CAMERA.position.z -= this.horizontalVelocity.x * delta;

this.horizontalVelocity.rotate(-direction);
this.horizontalVelocity.x *= forwardBackFriction ** delta;
this.horizontalVelocity.y *= leftRightFriction ** delta;
this.horizontalVelocity.rotate(direction);
```