# It's hard to move characters properly in Unity

Tags: unity, 3d, movement, character

I want to replicate the movement of a Team Fortress Scout in Unity, so the movement of the player must fall naturally, not slide, and not pass through objects. It must also be affected by `Addforce`.

I do not want to use `Addforce` and `Velocity` because they are slippery. Increasing the drag will make it less slippery, but it will decrease the fall speed.

When I move the character with `Transform.Translate`, the character passes through objects. To counter this, I placed a transparent box over the character to increase its thickness and used `Continuous Speculative`, but it still passed through.

A close approach would be to use `Transform.Translate` to move, `OverlapSphere` to detect walls, and slow down the character's speed, but this is not a desirable solution because the movement would be like sticking to a wall.

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: [Transform.Translate is not part of the physics system, so of course it will not respect colliders](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/154458/39518). Myself, [I like to implement this with a "traction" value I can use to blend between perfect, non-sliding control and free physics movement when knocked back / skating in ice](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/191346/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory: What is the difference between traction and friction?

Comment: Friction is a rate of energy dissipation. Traction a measure of control. If you want to get down to real-world physics, traction relies on friction, but for game feel tuning purposes I find it easier to think of it as its own knob I can adjust directly, rather than trying to juggle physics properties to indirectly achieve that end.